# strftime() with <> not giving the correct results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table:

```
| ID |   DOC_ID |       DATE | AMOUNT | PAID_AMOUNT | NET_BALANCE |            INS_DATE |            MOD_DATE | INDEX_ID |    STATUS | TRANSPORT | TRANS_DOC_ID | RETURNED | DATES |
|----|----------|------------|--------|-------------|-------------|---------------------|---------------------|----------|-----------|-----------|--------------|----------|-------|
| 30 | 41514635 | 2020-01-01 | 188.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        1 | PENDIENTE |       N/A |              |        0 |       |
| 30 | 41514635 | 2021-01-01 |  88.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        2 | PENDIENTE |       N/A |              |        0 |       |
| 30 | 41514635 | 2020-03-12 | 288.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        3 | PENDIENTE |       N/A |              |        0 |       |
| 30 | 41514635 | 2020-06-30 | 388.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        4 | PENDIENTE |       N/A |              |        0 |       |
```

I need a way to only show records besides the current month and year. example: today is `2021-01-08` I only need to see records besides month `01` and year `2021`

This is my [sql fiddle playground](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0eb5a7/3)

I do not understand why it doesn't output the result I want.

I need it to show me this:

```
| ID |   DOC_ID |       DATE | AMOUNT | PAID_AMOUNT | NET_BALANCE |            INS_DATE |            MOD_DATE | INDEX_ID |    STATUS | TRANSPORT | TRANS_DOC_ID | RETURNED | DATES |
|----|----------|------------|--------|-------------|-------------|---------------------|---------------------|----------|-----------|-----------|--------------|----------|-------|
| 30 | 41514635 | 2020-01-01 | 188.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        1 | PENDIENTE |       N/A |              |        0 |       |
| 30 | 41514635 | 2020-03-12 | 288.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        3 | PENDIENTE |       N/A |              |        0 |       |
| 30 | 41514635 | 2020-06-30 | 388.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        4 | PENDIENTE |       N/A |              |        0 |       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should be:

```
strftime('%Y%m', date) <> strftime('%Y%m', CURRENT_DATE)
```

The modifier `'%Y%m'` returns only the year/month part of the date, like `202101` and this is what you must compare to the same date part of the current date.

If you also want to include only `ID = 30` write the statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ClientRecord
WHERE ID = 30 AND strftime('%Y%m', date) <> strftime('%Y%m', CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY date DESC, ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f47192c4cb9dba71b1883dc0873d6f11).
Results:

```
> ID |   DOC_ID | DATE       | AMOUNT | PAID_AMOUNT | NET_BALANCE | INS_DATE            | MOD_DATE            | INDEX_ID | STATUS    | TRANSPORT | TRANS_DOC_ID | RETURNED | DATES
> -: | -------: | :--------- | -----: | ----------: | ----------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | -------: | :-------- | :-------- | :----------- | -------: | :----
> 30 | 41514635 | 2021-03-30 | 388.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        4 | PENDIENTE | N/A       |              |        0 |      
> 30 | 41514635 | 2020-03-12 | 288.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        3 | PENDIENTE | N/A       |              |        0 |      
> 30 | 41514635 | 2020-01-01 | 188.88 |           0 |       88.88 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 | 2021-01-01 20:57:44 |        1 | PENDIENTE | N/A       |              |        0 |
```